# Form Validation Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done a validation check in my form to check for email,username and firstname...here is the code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :email, :firstname, :username


    validates_format_of :email,
                    :with => /[-!#$&'*+\/=?`{|}~.\w]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]([-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]([-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+$/,
                    :message => ' appears to be invalid'
end
```

And in my view part is looking like this

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
       <ul>
       <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li>
          <%= msg %>
   </li>
       <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The issue is wenever validation fails, all the errors are listed above the form....I want the errors to be displayed corresponding to the textboxes.....how do i do that

Comment: At least you should give people credit for trying to answer your questions. And if the answers are not good enough, give explanation why not. I saw at least two questions where none of the answers got any upvote, whilst your questions where so general they seemed to be in the good direction at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this next to your check-box / text field or other form elements:

```
<%= @user.errors.on(:attribute_name) %>
```

Comment: thanks dude....also i have one more doubt......if i prefer to submit my form without entering any value in email field, am getting 2 errors at a time
* Email can't be blank
* Email appears to be invalid. 

How do i display only 1st comment

Answer (score 0):

model validation is really like that. if you want inline form validation, you can go checkout javascript form validation. My favorite is jquery's ketchup plugin:

http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/